# Argument is missing when using two functions in a post request using Plumber and R

Tags: r, api, prediction, plumber

I'm new to API builds. I'm trying to build an API using R's "Plumber" package, in order to predict using a Random Forest model.
Before the prediction I'm using a function I created that basically tries to clean up the incoming data.
This is my function:

```
testefun=function(table, train_data){
  table$reason = gsub('Compra de estoque', 'Compra_estoque', table$reason)
  table$reason = gsub('Capital de giro', 'Capital_giro', table$reason)
  table$reason = gsub('ConsolidaÃ§Ã£o de dÃ­vidas', 'Cons_div', table$reason)
  table$reason = gsub('Marketing e vendas', 'Mkt_vendas', table$reason)
  table$reason = gsub('ServiÃ§os', 'Servicos', table$reason)
  table$reason = gsub('Compra de equipamento', 'Compra_equip', table$reason)
  table$reason = gsub('ExpansÃ£o', 'Expansao', table$reason)
  names(table)[names(table) == "status"] <- "decision_motor"
  table$decision_motor = factor(table$decision_motor)
  table$decision_motor = gsub('in_founding', 'approved', table$decision_motor)
  table$decision_motor = gsub('in_progress', 'approved', table$decision_motor)
  table$score = factor(table$score)
  table$serasa = factor(table$serasa)
  table$pontualidade = factor(table$pontualidade)
  table$qualidade_divida = factor(table$qualidade_divida)
  table$bancabilidade = factor(table$bancabilidade)
  table$alavancagem = factor(table$alavancagem)
  table$porte = factor(table$porte)
  table$receita_recorrencias = factor(table$receita_recorrencias)
  table$respaldo_patrimonio = factor(table$respaldo_patrimonio)
  table$reputacional = factor(table$reputacional)
  table$impacto_covid = factor(table$impacto_covid)
  table$reason = factor(table$reason)
  table$decision_motor = factor(table$decision_motor)
  table$business_sector = factor(table$business_sector)
  table$state = factor(table$state)
  #Criar varíavel company_years
  table$foundation_date=as.Date(table$foundation_date)
  table$company_years=floor(age_calc(table$foundation_date, Sys.Date(), units = "years"))
  table=subset(table, select = -c(`foundation_date`))
  table=rbind(train_data[1,], table)
  table=table[-1,]
}
```

Basically what it does is fix the strange names that arrive in the raw data, calculate a new age variable, transform the necessary variables into a factor and finally, leave the qualitative variables with the same levels of the training data.
I'm trying to run a post request like this:

```
#* Predict
#* @post /predict

function(table, res){
  testefun(table, train2)
  data.frame(predict(model, newdata = as.data.frame(table$body), type="prob"))
}
```

When I try to enter the necessary parameters in Swagger, it returns the error:

```
simpleError in is.factor(x): argument "table" is missing, with no default
```

What can I do?

Comment: I think this fails the M portion of [MCVE]. Maybe make a smaller example and add the code needed to install and load packages (which needs the correct spelling of the package mentioned) and it could be a less difficult "learning opportunity" for someone to take a stab at it.

Comment: To anyone else attempting this. You will need the system package libsodium to get pkg: sodium and then pkg:plumber to install. And looking at it further it fails the C and V parts of MCVE as well. Need more info. Perhaps also include results of `traceback()` right after that error.

Comment: The way I solved my problem with this was by turning the categorical variables into dummy variables, I ran my model again.